# like another field concat in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to use this INNER JOIN statement...

```
INNER JOIN R_data as r on r.ids_logs LIKE CONCAT("%",l.id,"%")
```

...but I get this error message.

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5

Why was this error generated?

Comment: What is the rest of your query?  The (syntax) error is probably there.

Comment: no ,the rest of query works perfect without this line

Comment: Are you adding this line in the right position in your query?  Can you provide the rest of the query anyway?

Comment: `SELECT *
FROM l_table as l
LEFT JOIN c_table as c on l.id = c.id_log
INNER JOIN s_table as s on l.id=s.id_log
INNER JOIN R_data as r on r.ids_logs LIKE CONCAT("%",l.id,"%")`

Comment: Strange.  That's not giving me a syntax error.  Are you sure you don't have some weird unicode characters or something in there?

Comment: I don't think so

Comment: As pointed out by @JohnH, the double quotes should be single quotes.

Comment: @af_inb: Is this query inside a PHP string?

Comment: @MartijnBots: Assuming this query is in a PHP (or other language) variable.  If this is just SQL, then the quotes do not matter.

Comment: @RocketHazmat That's indeed true.

Comment: @RocketHaxmat: I recall that the initial post was displaying a character that looked sort of like a plus sign ( + ) at the end of the INNER JOIN statement, but that character is no longer being displayed after the posted question was updated.

Comment: No, @RocketHazmat the error it's on Sequel Pro

Comment: @JohnH: You're right.  I checked the post history and see that in the 1st revision, there was a weird character (appearing as a box in my Firefox) at the end of the Query.

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be an invalid character at the end of this INNER JOIN statement.

Try to remove that character and try again to execute this statement.

Comment: What character would that be?